# I was wondering how can a user in a group access a file made by a different user

Tags: command-line, permissions

For example, I made a file in my directory in a useracc and set the permissions as only groups can read that file
How can the user in that group get access to the file I made in my useracc and read that file? For ex: I made a file foo.txt in user bob is part of blue group and alice is part of red group , I want the file to appear in alice account since I set group permissions that groups can read.

Comment: One obvious solution is to add Alice to the blue group while keeping her red group membership.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions can be set for a group. Two users will have access if they are a member of the group. Thus, in your example, make "bob" also member of the "red" group. If it is not desired that "bob" has access to all files of the "red" group", then create a dedicated group for this specific project, and add all users that need access to the files of that project to this group.